# Ionic left sidemenu does not toggle open

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Hi I'm relatively new to ionic and I'm trying to get an app running with both a side-menu and a tab bar. Currently the tab bar is working fine just the left side menu does not open when I click the icon. For most of the app I've just been working off of the tutorials on the ionic website.

I am adding google maps to the tabs and I am aiming to have facebook login for the sidebar but the main issue is the tab isn't toggling.

## app.js

```
    $stateProvider

    .state('menu', {
      url: "/menu",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('menu.playlists', {
      url: "/playlists",
      views: {
        'menu' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
          controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })  

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })

    .state('tab.map', {
    url: '/map',
    views: {
      'tab-map': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-map.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
      }
    }
    })

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/map');
```

## tab-map.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Safety First">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

## menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menu" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/about">
          About
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="login()">
          Login
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

Here is an image of the app's main page

[image]

When I click the submenu icon it does not toggle the submenu. The odd part is that If I navigate the app to http://localhost:8100/#/menu/playlists the toggling is fine.

Any suggestions on why nothing is really firing on the click? Perhaps its an issue of which controller is acting at the time?

Comment: Not sure if it's the same as my case. It happens to me for similar case. My sidemenu shows but it shows behind the current page.

What I've done is I show a modal on a page, then from that modal I push another page. `NavController` for modal and page is not the same. If you need to navigate towards page from modal, I suggest to send in page's `NavController` and manage it via that object in modal class.

Note: ionic 2 rc-1

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the correct function. I'm assuming `login()` is located inside `AppCtrl` controller. Because of that, `ng-click` can't find the function, unless you tell it where it's located. Since `AppCtrl` is responsible for `menu.html`, you have to call it like this:

```
ng-click="this.login()"
```

Comment: To clarify. What I mean is nothing happens when you click the side menu button(in nav header) not when you click login(). I added some more detail in my post.